# New row is not displayed in the form array in mat-table

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, crud, mat-table

I use a form array in my mat-table and would like to add a new row to the table by clicking the add button. I wrote the logic for this. But nothing is shown to me. Can you tell me where my mistake is and how I can fix it?

My Code:

// HTML

```
<!-- Add rows -->
<button type="submit" mat-raised-button (click)="addRow()">add</button>

<!-- Table-Content -->
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let i = index;">
                <div formArrayName="rows" *ngIf="attributesWithFormControls.includes(column.attribute); else otherColumns">
                  <span class="edit-cell" [formGroupName]="i">
                      <mat-form-field>
                        <label>
                          <input matInput type="text" [formControlName]="column.attribute">
                        </label>
                      </mat-form-field>
                  </span>
                </div>
                <ng-template #otherColumns>
                  {{ column.object  !== null ? row[column.object][column.attribute] : row[column.attribute]  }}
                </ng-template>
              </td>
```

// TS

```
// For the form
calcBookingsForm: FormGroup;

// Variables for Data Table
  public columns = [];
  public dataSource: MatTableDataSource<MyModel> = null;

public displayedColumns: EditColumns[] = [
{ attribute: 'firstName', name: 'Firstname', object: null },
{ attribute: 'secondName', name: 'Lastname', object: null }
];

// Attributes defined here are displayed as input in the front end
public attributesWithFormControls = ['firstName', 'secondName'];

 ngOnInit(): void {
this.columns = this.displayedColumns.map(c => c.attribute);

 // CalcBookings form
    this.calcBookingsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      rows: this.formBuilder.array([this.initItemRows()])
    });
}

 get formArr() {
    return this.calcBookingsForm.get('rows') as FormArray;
  }

  initItemRows() {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      firstName: [''],
      lastName: [''],
    });
  }

// To add new row in the CalculatoryBookings
  addRow() {
    this.formArr.push(this.initItemRows())
  }
```

Comment: Hi. With that what i see i recomend You start from here https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview and next when You have table with  some static data move to next level.

Comment: Hello, yes the code snippets above did not contain the whole table. I have now created an example in Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l9x7ac?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html. But clicking the button still does not show me a new row in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Columns represent data types in rows, so adding a row to a table is like adding an empty record. It depends what you want to do with the data in a new row when entering the data you have to add another logic for the behavior of the row when saving the new data, in this example I am teaching how to add a new row.
Html file with table and one button to add row:

```
<div style="margin-top: 64px; margin-left: 64px;">
    <button (click)="AddRow()" mat-raised-button>Add</button>
</div>

<div style="margin-top: 64px;"></div>
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" multiTemplateDataRows class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="{{column}}" *ngFor="let column of columnsToDisplay">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{column}} </th>

        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
            <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput [value]="element[column]" />
            </mat-form-field>
        </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: columnsToDisplay;">
    </tr>
</table>
```

Class with data that You want to add:

```
export interface ProductElement {
  name: string;
  id: string;
  color: string;
  year: number;
  price: number;
}
```

Data to create rows with example data:

```
// List of Brands
  brands: string[] = ['Vapid', 'Carson', 'Kitano', 'Dabver', 'Ibex', 'Morello', 'Akira', 'Titan', 'Dover', 'Norma'];
  // List of Colors
  colors: string[] = ['Black', 'White', 'Red', 'Blue', 'Silver', 'Green', 'Yellow'];
  // Column definition
  columnsToDisplay: string[] = ['id', 'name', 'year', 'color', 'price'];
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<ProductElement>;
```

Method for create random data:

```
generateName = () => {
    return this.brands[Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(10))];
  }

  generatePrice = () => {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(50000) + 1);
  }

  generateColor = () => {
    return this.colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(7))];
  }

  generateYear = () => {
    return 2000 + Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(19));
  }

  createId(): string {
    let id = '';
    const chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      id += chars.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length));
    }
    return id;
  }
```

method to add new row:

```
newRow = () => {
    const data = {
      id: this.createId(),
      name: this.generateName(),
      year: this.generateYear(),
      color: this.generateColor(),
      price: this.generatePrice(),
    };
    return data;
  }
```

and method to add new row with sample data.

```
AddRow(): void {
    ELEMENT_DATA.push(this.newRow());
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<ProductElement>(ELEMENT_DATA);
  }
```

Finaly result:
[image: Resultado]

Practice with this and you will tell me how it goes.
Update:
in You example if You change Add method like below its work
[image]
Result:

[image]